# Is it possible to get an MSDN help (local or website) for a selected Intellisense dropdown function using a kb shortcut?

Tags: visual-studio, intellisense, msdn

So, very often do I wonder what a function does and open up a browser and head to MSDN to check more comprehensive description. Is there a keyboard shortcut I could use to open up the MSDN page of the selected function in the Intellisense dropdown automatically?

Comment: You do have MSDN installed locally?

Answer (score 0):

I usually just press Enter to insert it into the source code, then press F1 which takes you to the help of the identifier under the cursor. I'm not sure if there's one for taking you there straight from the drop-down, but a simple Ctrl+Z removes the inserted identifier later.

Answer (score 0):

You can press F1 when your cursor is on the function.  It will show you the MSDN help of the function.  You don't even need to highlight it